# How to change default spring profil ("cloud") in cloud foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-profiles

I want to launch my spring-boot application after a `cf push` with a custom profile named `my_profile`, but the app is always launched with the default one `cloud` profile. How can I specify the exact profile to load?

I already tried to add the environment variable in the manifest.yml like this:

```
env:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: my_profile
```

But the application was load with both profiles (`cloud` & `my_profile`)

Do you have a solution to load juste my custom profile and not integrate the default one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is coming from the Java buildpack and it's Spring Auto-reconifguration support.

> The Spring Auto-reconfiguration Framework adds the cloud profile to any existing Spring profiles such as those defined in the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-spring_auto_reconfiguration.md

To disable this behavior, you can disable the Spring Auto-reconfiguration support.

Set an env variable `JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION` to `{ enabled: false }`.

Ex:

```
cf set-env my-cool-app JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION '{ enabled: false }'
```

Please note that this will also disable the `cloud.*` properties and automatic rewriting of bean to configure services.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration#what-is-auto-reconfiguration

Comment: Daniel can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163062/java-lang-illegalstateexception-pcf

Answer (score 2):

You can also add this inside manifest.yaml as below:

```
env:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: my_profile
  JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{ enabled: false }'
```