# java.lang.IllegalStateException: PCF

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am working on spring boot and I am trying to read the credentials from PCF environment. For that I am using `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` as dependency.

**MyMain.java**

```
@PostConstruct
    public void intProcess() {
        try {
            Cloud cloud = new CloudFactory().getCloud();
            OracleServiceInfo serviceInfo = (OracleServiceInfo) cloud.getServiceInfo("DbDetails");
            DataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSourceCreator().create(serviceInfo, null);
            JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
            template.setDataSource(dataSource);
        } catch (CloudException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in DB connection:" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in DB connection:" + ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

**Application.properties:-**

```
    spring.profiles.active=cloud
```

**Manifest.yml:-**

```
applications:
- name: name
  memory: 1G
  instances: 1
  path: ./target/1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  services:
    - DbDetails
  env:
    JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{ jre: { version: 11.+ } }'
    JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors
            </artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

With the above code I am getting the

```
ERROR --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
2021-06-28T17:18:15.683+05:30 [OUT] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exiting the application since the Spring Cloud Connector library has been detected on the classpath. Please remove this dependency from your project and set the environment variable JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION '{enabled: false}' in the Cloud Foundry manifest.
```

Comment: Basically, it's telling you not to use Spring Cloud Connector. That project has been deprecated. It's recommended you use: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv going forward. Is there a reason you need SCC?

Comment: @DanielMikusa Need to read the oracle credentials from PCF env Hence I am using SCC

Comment: OK, but you should be ablw to use java-cfenv with Oracle too. It's a supported Db.